# Finding roll/pitch/yaw for rotating local vector to another vector

Tags: reference-frames, coordinate-systems, rotation

Although I looked into similar questions regarding this subject, I could not make the link to my situation so correct me if the answer is already on StackExchange...

My starting point is a global xyz-frame and a local FLU-frame (airplane) which is aligned with the xyz-frame (F/x, L/y, U/z). The local FLU-frame does roll/pitch/yaw using the matrix defined at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Conventions_by_extrinsic_rotations), Tait–Bryan angles $Z_1X_2Y_3$. What I need is the rotation matrix that rotates a local normalized vector $V$ in the FLU-frame to a global normalized vector $W$ in the xyz-frame. The application is that the local vector $V$ can be defined on the airplane and then the whole airplane is rotated such that $V$ 'looks at' coordinates $W$. So we have $W=RV$, with $V$ and $W$ known and $R$ the rotation matrix to be determined. Oh, next step is that I want to rotate the rotated airplane around that vector $W$ afterwards, but first get this step working.

Some things I tried or thought of:

- Skipping one rotation to make life simpler is not possible, in many cases you need all three.
- Just calculating a matrix which transforms $V$ to $W$ (divide) does not work because it does not result in a rotation matrix.
- I tried to find the roll/pitch angles such that the transformed U-axis has the same angle with $W$ as with the transformed $V$ so an additional yaw-rotation (around the transformed U...) then suffices, but it becomes really messy quite soon with unclear conditions for the required roll and pitch solutions. Or my analysis approach was wrong...
- stuck...

Comment: You can think about the rotation of your FLU frame as rotation of the vector $\vec V$ to $\vec{W}$: $\vec{W} = R \,\, \vec{V}, $
where you can find the matrix $R$ in the mentioned Wiki page. You need to solve the for $\vec{V}$, which you can do by multiplying the equality above by $  R^{-1}$ from left:
$ \vec{V} = R^{-1} \,\, \vec{W}. $

Comment: $R$ indeed rotates $V$ to $W$ but both vectors are known and $R$ is unknown and needs to be calculated.